# Register/Login System in python using binary files

Tags: python-2.7, binaryfiles

The following script does not seem to do the required thing. There are no errors. The program just doesnt do anything while execution.
Please tell me what is wrong in the code because ive NOT BEEN ABLE TO FIGURE OUT THE PROBLEM for a quite a long time now.

```
class user_register:   #GENERAL AUTOMATIC FUNCTION
    def __init__(self):
        self.username=''
        self.password=''
    def storedata(self):
        self.username=raw_input('Enter username:-')
        self.password=raw_input('Enter password:-')
        ur=user_register
        f=open("user.dat","a+b")

        status=0

        try:
             while True:

                 ur= pickle.load(f)

                 if ur.username == self.username:
                     print '---------------------'
                     print 'USERNAME HAS ALREADY BEEN TAKEN......please try again'
                     ur.storedata()
                 if len(self.password)<8:
                     print'2'
                     print 'PLEASE ENTER A PASSWORD CONTAINING MORE THAN 8 CHARACTERS!!                                                     `
                     ur.storedata()

         except EOFError:
             pickle.dump(ur,f)
             print 'YOU HAVE BEEN SUCCESSFULLY REGISTERED'
             f.close()



class user_login: #GENERAL AUTOMATIC FUNCTION

    def __init__(self):

        self.username=''
        self.password=''

    def storedata(self):
        self.username=raw_input('Enter username:-')
        self.password=raw_input('Enter password:-')
        username=self.username
        password=self.password

        user_check(username,password)

def user_check(u,p):
    f1=open("user.dat","rb")
    ul=user_login

    try:
        while True:
            ul=pickle.load(f1)
            if ul.username==u and ul.password==p :
                 print 'LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!!'
                user_main_menu()
            else:
                print 'Wrong combination of username/password!! Please try again!!!!'
                ul.storedata()

    except EOFError:
        f1.close()

def main():
    ur=user_register()
    ur.storedata
    ul=user_login()
    ul.storedata
main()
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Also, what is `ur=user_register` supposed to do?

Comment: object - class binding which if not done wolud lead to an unresolved refrence.

Comment: Like i said it is a part of a much bigger program that im working on. This particular module doesnt seem to work right. user_register contains the classobjects storedata to get the input(username and password) from the new user and check if the username is already in use or not by checking the binary file. If accepted the input data will be dumped into the file. user_login checks if the existing username and password are correct or not by checking it in the SAME binary file.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
print 'PLEASE ENTER A PASSWORD CONTAINING MORE THAN 8 CHARACTERS!!
```

is missing a closing quote `'`. Additionally, in `main()`, the statements `ur.storedata` and `ul.storedata` don't do anything. If you are running a function, you need to include parentheses `()`:

```
ul.storedata()
```

Comment: Actually both user_register and user_login are classes in which funcs. like storedata is contained. Hence , the method employed in th program is the correct one. BTW the problem i raised was not a syntax or run time error. Instead it is a logical error that is not giving me the right output.